# Twilio setup missed call to voicemail

Tags: xml, twilio, voicemail

I currently have one phone number that I setup to go directly to my mobile via TwiML Bin where under the Active Numbers/ A call comes in: TwiML Bin is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial answerOnBridge="true">
<Sip><phonenumber>@<phonenumber>.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip></Dial>
</Response>
```

How can I add a go to voicemail with the TwiML bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Thank you for calling.</Say>
  <Say>Please Leave a message after the tone</Say>
  
  <Record transcribe="true" timeout="90" transcribeCallback="http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=Email.com"/>
</Response>
```

In case I can not answer the phone? I am completely new to this. and did not understand this response " [How to Setup Voicemail with Twilio SIP Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933187/how-to-setup-voicemail-with-twilio-sip-endpoint) " Thank you