# How to add a call relay using twilio studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to create a call relay using `twilio studio`.

So far I can make call to a single number. I want to forward the call to another number if the first number is in busy. I am using `2nd line` mobile app for testing this feature.

I am new to stack overflow, Help me with the details of how the call forwarding flow in a `twilio studio`.

**Update**

To make the relay of calls ,I placed two `Connect Call To` widgets and make contact with `Connected call ended` terminal of first widget to the input terminal of the second widget. The flow of calling is working, but some times the flow breaks. The `User pressed keys` are not recognizing properly. Did you faced this type of issue?

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145791/diverting-twilio-call-to-voicemail-if-unanswered

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz I have updated the question with some findings, can you go through it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to feed the first Twilio Studio Connect Call To widget into a Split Based on Widget. Then in the Split Based on Widget, check the previous Widgets DialCallStatus to determine if the call was anything but completed.

The variable you are checking in the Split Based on Widget would look like this, accounting for changes in you Connect Call To Widget name:

```
{{widgets.connect_call_1.DialCallStatus}}
```

You can then feed that into another Connect Call To widget (if it doesn't equal completed), and place the call to the next party. This way, the second party doesn't receive a call if the first party successfully answered the call.

Similar logic is covered in this Twilio Function for handling voicemail, https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/tutorials/communications-guides/implement-voicemail.